# Which electronic parts/systems are responsible when installing an OS to an empty PC?

Tags: system

I´m wondering there must be some already commands inside a computer to be able to install OS such as Windows. Somewhere there must be a programmed chip or something. Is that DOS? Any introduction link about this appreciated.

Comment: Useful search term : BIOS

Comment: Its called the [BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) or [UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) A small piece of firmware that runs before anything else.  Typically after setting up some of the hardware it will just boot from the hard disk or other device containing your OS of choice.

Comment: This is not about electrical engineering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a electronics question, so I'll be brief since it will likely be closed.

What you are really asking is how a computer boots up.  For a typical PC, this is done by a small stripped down OS called the "bios" stored in non-volatile memory.  Go look it up.